# How to allow configurable shortcuts for all languages, i.e. how to map unicode keystrokes to javax.swing.KeyStroke?

Tags: java, unicode, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keystroke

I want to allow a shortcut configuration for my application that works around the world. That's why I load them from resource bundles. I first wanted to simply put the resource value for the shortcut directly to `javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(String)`, but that doesn't work for unicode keyboards, e.g. arabic:

```
KeyStroke test = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control ش");
// test is null, i.e. it did not work
```

<kbd>ش</kbd> is the arabic keyboard key of <kbd>A</kbd>.

Is there a easy way to allow `String` definition of international keystrokes for java?

Comment: What do chinese keyboards keys send if one presses <kdb>A</kbd>? In elcipse I get a popup with 10 different chinese symbols, i.e. how do chinese shortcuts work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work with pressed keystrokes:

```
KeyStroke test = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control typed ش");
// test not null, works
```

Comment: you get the keystroke that way, but this high level typed event cannot be used for keyboard action shortcuts... :( see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814845/how-to-define-readable-shortcuts-for-international-keyboards